# Pandas Datetime aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

So I currently have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
    DATE_LOCAL  consomation  temperature  site         day  month  \
278455 2012-11-27 23:10:00           34          5.6  ID18  2012-11-27     11   
278456 2012-11-27 23:20:00           40          5.6  ID18  2012-11-27     11   
278457 2012-11-27 23:30:00           33          5.6  ID18  2012-11-27     11   
278458 2012-11-27 23:40:00           22          5.6  ID18  2012-11-27     11   
278459 2012-11-27 23:50:00           35          5.6  ID18  2012-11-27     11   

        week_day  hour NAF code  consomation_day  temperature_day  
278455         1    23   Hotels        29.465278             6.75  
278456         1    23   Hotels        29.465278             6.75  
278457         1    23   Hotels        29.465278             6.75  
278458         1    23   Hotels        29.465278             6.75  
278459         1    23   Hotels        29.465278             6.75
```

I've used the below to aggregate for the average of temperature / consomation for a specific day:

```
data['consomation_day'] = data.groupby(['day','site'])['consomation'].transform(lambda v: v.mean())
```

My goal now is to do the same thing for _previous_day, _day_of_previous_week, and weekly_average. These are proving to be much much more tricky and I'd appreciate any nudge in the right direction I could get. If I need to formulate my question better, let me know! I'm fairly new around here.

Comment: Sorry but can't help to downvote when you share a screenshot. Please copy that data by using print(data.tail(10)) or possibly print(data.tail(10).to_dict()).

Comment: Is the edit what you want?

Comment: Now it is. ....

Comment: I can have a look soon, upvoted now.

Comment: Ok this was a bit trickier than I initially thought.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who feels that way lol! This is my first time really working with datetimes more heavily than pulling out days or months etc. It feels very tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a step in the right direction?? Full simplified example.

```
import pandas as pd
data = '''\
DATE_LOCAL                    co  temperature  site   NAFcode
2012-11-26T23:10:00           34          5.6  ID18    Hotels
2012-11-27T23:10:00           34          5.6  ID18    Hotels
2012-11-28T23:20:00           40          5.6  ID18    Hotels
2012-11-28T23:30:00           33          5.6  ID18    Hotels
2012-11-29T23:40:00           22          5.6  ID18    Hotels
2012-12-02T23:50:00           35          5.6  ID18    Hotels
2012-12-03T23:50:00           35          5.6  ID18    Hotels
2012-12-04T23:50:00           35          5.6  ID18    Hotels'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', parse_dates=['DATE_LOCAL'])

df['PD_date'] = (df['DATE_LOCAL'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=24)).dt.date
df['PW_date'] = (df['DATE_LOCAL'] - pd.Timedelta(days=7)).dt.date

# Assign new help columns
df['date'] = df['DATE_LOCAL'].dt.date
df['week'] = df['DATE_LOCAL'].dt.year.map(str)+df['DATE_LOCAL'].dt.week.map(str)

# Create a mask and assign
m = df.groupby(['date','site'])['co'].mean().to_dict()
df['co_day'] = df[['date','site']].apply(tuple, 1).map(m)
df['co_pday'] = df[['PD_date','site']].apply(tuple, 1).map(m)
df['co_pweek'] = df[['PW_date','site']].apply(tuple, 1).map(m)

# Calculate rolling 7 days (week) mean
m = df.groupby(['date','site'])['co'].mean().rolling(7, min_periods=1).mean().to_dict()
df['co_week'] = df[['date','site']].apply(tuple,1).map(m)

# Drop help-columns
df = df.set_index('date').drop(
    ['DATE_LOCAL','PD_date','NAFcode','PW_date','week'],axis=1)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
            co  temperature  site  co_day  co_pday  co_pweek    co_week
date                                                                   
2012-11-26  34          5.6  ID18    34.0      NaN       NaN  34.000000
2012-11-27  34          5.6  ID18    34.0     34.0       NaN  34.000000
2012-11-28  40          5.6  ID18    36.5     34.0       NaN  34.833333
2012-11-28  33          5.6  ID18    36.5     34.0       NaN  34.833333
2012-11-29  22          5.6  ID18    22.0     36.5       NaN  31.625000
2012-12-02  35          5.6  ID18    35.0      NaN       NaN  32.300000
2012-12-03  35          5.6  ID18    35.0     35.0      34.0  32.750000
2012-12-04  35          5.6  ID18    35.0     35.0      34.0  33.071429
```

Comment: Yes! This definitely gets me going. I appreciate it.

Comment: Ya I'll need 7 days ago's average basically. I'm about to try and whip it up right now.

Comment: Ya so for example: If today is monday, last mondays averages

Comment: The previous 7 days

Comment: @JustinZint How about now? Maybe the rolling window should not include the current...

Comment: @JustinZint I just remembered we could just shift the with 1 (but this would require us to have all dates). Anyway good luck!